# Constructors With Same Arguments?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a WinForm that I want to be able to construct using two different ID values.  So for instance:

```
var f1 = new Form(table1Id);
var f2 = new Form(table2Id);
```

The first constructor would build the form based on data in table1, the second constructor would build the form based on data in table2.  The problem is, if I have two constructors that take an int, there is no differentiating between the two.  What is the best way around this problem?

Comment: Are Table1 and Table2 the same structure?

Comment: Why do you think you need two different `int` constructors?  f1 and f2 are different instances of Form.  Just have Form(int) do the right thing initializing each new instance based on the value of the passed-in `int`.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between the constructors? Nothing in your above code/text suggests that this is necessary.

Comment: @Eric, it seems that the integers go to different *tables*, that's not to say that the tables can be determined simply based upon the integer values.

Comment: If numbers in the same range can convey different meaning, then you're coding this wrong. Might it not be better to create a complex object that contains the number and effectively annotates which usage is meant? It will also mean that you no longer have the argument conflict that you currently face.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a factory approach instead of a constructor. Named methods are a way to disambiguate when the parameter types are the same but mean different things. For example

```
public static Form CreateFromTable1(int id)
{
    // instantiate, build form
    return form;
}

public static Form CreateFromTable2(int id)
{
    // instantiate, build form
    return form;
}
```

Comment: Yes... but... there's no reason not do do the same thing with a normal constructor.  Factory pattern is most useful if the factory may need to return different implementations of an interface depending on the circumstances.

Comment: What are you thoughts on this: If I have a single constructor and initializer functions, this would be more intuitive for people looking at the code for the first time.  If there were no cosntructors, and only factory functions, it would be less intuitive to people who have never seen the code before?  So I hate to poopoo your suggestion, but it seems like using a constructor and initializers is the more ... obvious thing to do?

Comment: @Eric You are talking about the “factory method” pattern, but Anthony isn’t; he’s just talking about builder methods (aka. factory methods, to add to the confusion), which are entirely appropriate in similar circumstances. However, I don’t think this is what the OP is after.

Comment: @sooprise, think of where you are. You have two constructors, each taking integers. They each do different things (build from different tables). You have no way to disambiguate these constructors. You *could* consolidate to a single constructor, introducing an extra parameter (perhaps an enum) to identify the behavior (table) to use, but then you have a constructor that is doing 2 different things. It's therefore my suggestion to utilize an approach as demonstrated in my answer. If another answer makes more sense to you, by all means, go with it.

Comment: @Anthony, It seems like that most people agree that using factory methods is the preferable solution in this case.  I will go ahead and use this method.

Comment: I disagree that any sort of class construction paradigm is best - no factory pattern, no "factory method" (which is just another way to implement the factory pattern without a separate factory class).  Austin Salonen's answer hits the nail on the head.

Comment: @Eric, I also agreed with and voted on Austin's answer, if indeed the case is that the form is itself wearning many hats. On the other hand, it could just be that data it needs come from different places, but the form itself doesn't treat it differently once its constructed. It will be up to the OP as to what makes most sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm(int id)
    {
         // logic to distinguish id goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the allowable integers for each form were in the same range

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing code it's hard to confirm this, but by your very explanation this class is violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Assuming the forms only differ by data, have the constructor take the actual data instead IDs, which I assume are used to get the data.

If they differ substantially by the content, they should be two distinct forms (possible with a common, abstract parent class).

Based on my past experiences, having that *one form to rule them all* mentality is just going to create a maintenance nightmare.  Spend some time studying the SOLID principles (S = Single Responsibility Principle) and you'll be pleasantly surprised with the code you start writing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd create an Enum and pass one of its values as an argument, indicating what kind of table is given.

Answer (score -2):

I would use an Initialize method, something like:

```
var f1  = new Form();
f1.InitA(table1Id);
var f2  = new Form();
f2.InitB(table2Id);
```

Comment: Sorry, I can’t not downvote this. This is just incredibly bad style: you are effectively using methods where you should have used constructors, and making the actual constructor useless.

Comment: So using factory methods is better than this approach?   This actually seems like an intuitive solution to the problem since you have one common constructor, and build upon your returned form from there...

Comment: No problem, this is what downvoting is made for :) However, I think it would be a suitable solution if there's no other possibility to differentiate the parameters.

Comment: @sooprise *If* factory methods are the appropriate solution then yes, they are infinitely better than this method. This method here leaves objects in an uninitialised state (after constructor call, but before `Init`) without good reason. This is code smell. However, I’m still not convinced that factory methods are needed in your case, and that a normal constructor wouldn’t be sufficient.